# In javascript, how do I match multiple occurrences of a sub string in a string using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried using `'/bkickstarter/b'` but its not able to match with the text like this: `I backed this: http://kickstarter.com`

Update:

```
var regex = new RegExp("/\bkickstarter\b/g");
console.log("zach braff's new movie is now being backed on kickstarter: http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1869987317/wish-i-was-here-1 … also, a documentary on a swartz:  http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/26788492/aaron-swartz-documentary-the-internets-o".match(regex));
```

That prints a null.

Comment: What is `/b.../b`? Did you mean `\b`? And what exactly are you trying to match? "kickstarter" only appears once anyways

Answer (score 3):

You probably wanted to use `\b` not `b`.

```
"I backed this: http://kickstarter.com".match(/\bkickstarter\b/);
```

If you want to match all occurrences of the regex, add `/g` modifier.

```
"I backed this: http://kickstarter.com kickstarter".match(/\bkickstarter\b/g);
```

Comment: Have updated the question. When I tried your method, it returned null.

Comment: @Hick, if you want to initialize with `new RegExp`, you don't need the `/` at the start and end, you need to escape `\b`, and `g` should be passed as second parameter. So `new RegExp("\\bkickstarter\\b", "g")` will work.

Answer (score 0):

remove `/b /b` It will search for only separate words, and here you require any string containing 'kickstarter'.

instead put `/kickstarter/i` for case insensitive search

Answer (score 0):

The reason `var regex = new RegExp("/\bkickstarter\b/g");` doesn't work is because the `\` has special meaning in string literal syntax as the start of an escape sequence, so the `\` ends up being removed.

To use a `\` charater in a string, you need to escape it, which means it'll look like `\\`, so your final regex

```
var regex = new RegExp("/\\bkickstarter\\b/g");
```